# pfSense - Site to Site OpenVPN

Tags: vpn, pfsense

I have two pfSense 2.1 servers running with LANs of 192.168.0.0/24 and 192.168.10.0/24. The pfSense servers are 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.10.1

I just configured an OpenVPN site to site tunnel, that *appears* to be working fine. From each of the pfSense servers I can ping the other (from 192.168.0.1 I can ping 192.168.10.1 and the other way around) but from the computers on my LAN, I can't reach the other LAN.

What could be causing that?

Comment: Are there routes set up so the firewalls know to route traffic to each other?

Comment: Yes, there are routes after I connect.

Comment: What does the FW log say? Any blocks? What does a traceroute say from a client to the other LAN?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways this could go wrong.

```
1. Routing
```

Are the OpenVPN servers set up as default gateways for their respective networks? If no, that's your answer.

```
2. Packet forwarding
```

Are the pfSense servers allowing packet forwarding? In other words, can you send packets through them, from one network interface to another?

```
3. Packet filter
```

Is the local firewall on the pfSense servers allowing packets to be forwarded like that? Maybe there's a forward rule that blocks those packets.

Comment: Just a nit: the VPN endpoints *no not* need to be the default gateway. Rather, the clients or the routers at each site need to have a static route specified for the other site's subnet.

Answer (score 1):

Most important thing in this regard are firewall rules. Mostly people forget to add firewall rules for OVPN traffic

1. Rules at OPENVPN tab. For example
   [image: Allow traffic from OpenVPN]
2. Rules at WAN tab
   [image]

Since both ends of your tunnel are pinging then i would double check the rules in the  OpenVPN tab.

If these are all correct then you need to check the routing. Hope it helps.